# Should support questions be asked on SE?

Tags: discussion, community-guidelines

A couple of questions have been opened, which seems more appropriate for a Sitecore support case.

For example,

[Sitecore Azure deployment error - Sitecore.Azure.UI.Pipelines.PreAutomation.CheckHostedService failed](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/sitecore-azure-deployment-error)

[Unable to change DisplayName of the item](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/unable-to-change-displayname-of-the-item)

Are these questions valid for SE, or should they be directed to Sitecore support instead?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it matters whether or not a question is fit to be directed to Sitecore support. If it's a good question that is on-topic and has enough detail, then it can be answered by the community. The benefit of that is that the answer will be available to the public, as opposed to Sitecore support answers that can only be seen by the person asking.

If you think that a question is unfit for this site's format, you can vote to close it, or advice how it can be improved using comments.

The decision of whether or not a question needs to be closed should be based solely on the assessment if it's a good fit *for this site*.

Comment: I am aware of the mechanics of the voting system, I was asking for a general opinion here. If the general opinion is that the questions are welcome, I won't be close-voting them.

Comment: @KasperGadensgaard The thing is, you shouldn't base your voting on whether a question is a good fit for another site. You should vote based on whether it's a good fit _for this site_.

Comment: Agree, so that is actually the essence of my question (and why i tagged it discussion).

Answer (score 2):

They're valid. In essence; pretty much any question we see coming through here - could also have been directed to Sitecore Support.

Often so; many of the errors people experience (including the two you linked) will have been experienced and fixed by members of the community.

Comment: Most other questions are more of "how-tos", while these seems to report on bugs on core functionality - thus I think they are different in nature. Your point is valid though.

Comment: Many people don't know that at the time of posting however. More often than not; it ends up being configuration errors.